# Como fazer uma implementação genérica do método da Bisecção em MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matemática

Boa noite,

Estou tendo o seguinte problema:

- O código desenvolvido em Matlab para calcular raízes da equação usando método da bisecção está bugando, talvez no processo de calculo (loops);
- A ideia é a seguinte:
  O usuário entrar com a função que deseja, intervalos, tolerância desejada e a quantidade de iterações.

```
clc
clear


%Recebe a Função desejada
disp('Insira a sua função');
f = input('=> ','s');

%Recebe os Intervalos desejados
disp('Insira os valor do Intervalo Xa');
Xa = input('=> '); %Recebe o valor do intervalo A
disp('Insira os valor do Intervalo Xb: ');
Xb = input('=> '); %Recebe o valor do intervalo B

%Recebe a Tolerancia desejada
disp('Insira a Tolerancia desejada');
tolerancia_desejada = input('=>'); %Recebe o valor do erro desejado

%Recebe a quantidade de Operações
disp('Insira o numero de interações');
iteracoes_desejada = input('=> '); %Recebe o valor da quantidade de iterações que o usuário deseja

%Processamento dos Dados
aux = 1;

if((subs(f,Xa))*(subs(f,Xb))>0)
    fprintf('Essa função não existe');
else
    if((subs(f(Xa))*(subs(f,Xb))<0))
        fprintf('Essa função tem raiz');
    end
end

while(aux<iteracoes_desejada)
    media = (Xa+Xb)/2;
    if(subs((f(Xa))*(subs(f(media))<0)))
        Xb = media;
    else
        Xa = media;
    end
    if abs(subs((f(media))<tolerancia_desejada))
        break
    end
end

%Exibindo Resultado da Operação
fprintf('A Raiz é: %f',media);
```

Comment: qual exatamente o erro do seu código? se possível coloque na sua questão pra facilitar quem te ajuda a achar resposta (:
você não está atualizando a sua variável `aux` em nenhum lugar, o que possivelmente está resultando em um loop infinito.

Comment: Não seria um erro, mais sim problema (acredito). Eu quero que o usuário final tenha a possibilidade de inserir a função desejada. Pois, pelos programas de terceiros, eles apenas colocam ou modificam a equação já dentro do código...

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim isolar o método no MATLAB. Para isso, você precisa usar `function handlers`

A função a seguir implementa o método da bissecção:

```matlab
function [x, err] = rootBissect(fn, xMin, xMax, tol)
    a = xMin;
    b = xMax;
    err = b-a;
    while err > tol
        x = (b+a)/2;
        if fn(x) * fn(a) > 0 
            a = x;
        else
            b = x;
        end
        err = b - a;
    end
end
```

Repare que eu estou passando a função como parâmetro (`fn`).

Para calcular uma raíz do seno por exemplo você pode fazer assim:

```matlab
[x, err] = rootBissect(@sin, 3, 3.2, 0.001)
```

Repare o `@` na frente da função `sin`. Isso faz com que um handler para a função seno seja passado de modo que a função é chamada dentro de `rootBissect`.

Neste exemplo específico você vai obter a resposta:

```
x =

    3.1414


err =

   7.8125e-04
```

Que faz sentido pois pi é uma das raízes do seno (e a que a gente procurava no intervalo fornecido).